# Corona app stops on Android, when trying to change scene after a video is finished

Tags: android, video, storyboard, coronasdk, scene

I have a main.lua, that tells my app to go to another a scene (intro.lua), which is a video playing, and after the video is completed, I want to go to a third scene which is my game menu (menu.lua).

The problem is that my Android app stops, when the video is completed. It doesnt go to the "menu" scene.

My code is as follows:

**My main.lua:**

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

system.setIdleTimer( false )
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )


yourName=""
labName=""
titleName=""
rememberMusic=1
rememberSound=1
remeberMusicSlider=300
remeberSoundSlider=300

sndMusic = audio.loadStream ( "Audio/ambient.mp3" )
sndClick = audio.loadStream ( "Audio/click.mp3" )

storyboard.gotoScene("intro")

return scene
```

**My video intro.lua:**

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

system.setIdleTimer( false )
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local onComplete = function()

   storyboard.gotoScene("menu")
end
media.playVideo( "videos/logo.mp4", false, onComplete )

return scene
```

My menu.lua is huge, I cannot post it here. But it has no problem. If I call it from my main.lua, it works great. If I call it from my intro.lua (without the video) it works great.

BUT if I call it (as written in the code above) WHEN the video is completed, the app stops.

Anyone has an idea what is going on?

**The error from Eclipse:**

```
07-05 17:52:22.111: W/dalvikvm(448): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410f5930)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.ansca.corona.VideoActivity$1.onCompletion(VideoActivity.java:48)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.widget.VideoView$3.onCompletion(VideoView.java:361)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1980)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-05 17:52:22.121: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 17:52:22.131: W/ActivityManager(478):   Force finishing activity com.demigod.biolab/com.ansca.corona.VideoActivity
07-05 17:52:22.271: D/dalvikvm(478): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 708K, 29% free 17351K/24288K, paused 110ms, total 112ms
07-05 17:52:22.791: W/ActivityManager(478): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41e855c0 u0 com.demigod.biolab/com.ansca.corona.VideoActivity}
07-05 17:52:22.981: I/hwcomposer(125): Setting interactive mode: On
07-05 17:52:32.291: W/ActivityManager(478): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-05 17:52:32.801: W/ActivityManager(478): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{41ccb8d8 u0 com.demigod.biolab/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity}
```

Comment: did you see any error message maybe there so many things you load on your code

Comment: I can't debug it in the simulator cause I work on windows, and the simulator on windows does not support video playback. The only error I get is at my physical android device (nexus 7), which says "Unfortunately, your application has stopped".

Comment: you can use eclipse and android sdk to see your error

Comment: I use Corona, not android sdk.

Comment: yes i know you can use eclipse to see your error on your device because i'm using it whenever i debug on my devices

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(32016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 17:26:19.851: E/AndroidRuntime(32016): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 17:26:19.851: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):  at com.ansca.corona.VideoActivity$1.onCompletion(VideoActivity.java:48)
07-05 17:26:19.851: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):  at android.widget.VideoView$3.onCompletion(VideoView.java:361)
07-05 17:26:19.851: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):  at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1980)----------------------
This is what I get from Eclipse. I don't know what it is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32963/discussion-between-devfar-and-user2347313)

Answer (score 0):

in your onComplete try to remove the video before you go to your next scene

```
local myVideo
local onComplete = function()
   --remove your video here
   myVideo:removeSelf()
   storyboard.gotoScene("menu")
end
myVideo = media.playVideo( "videos/logo.mp4", false, onComplete )
```

or maybe your using unsupported format try to visit this link
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/playVideo.html

Comment: can you post the full stack of the error and edit your question with the error